# Google Cloud Vision OCR API returning incorrect values for bounding box/vertices

Tags: api, bounding-box, vertices, google-cloud-vision

I'm using the "TEXT_DETECTION" option from the Google Cloud Vision API to OCR some images.

The bounding box around individual characters is sometimes accurate and sometimes not, often within the same image.

Is this a normal side-effect of a probabilistic nature of the vision algorithm, a bug in the Vision API, or of course an issue with how I'm interpreting the response?

[image: Image annotated with text and bounding boxes from Google Vision OCR API]

[image: The letter "a" with poor bounding box]

Here's the portion of the response specific to the letter "a" from which I'm extracting the bounding box.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [property] => stdClass Object
        (
            [detectedLanguages] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [languageCode] => en
                        )

                )

        )

    [boundingBox] => stdClass Object
        (
            [vertices] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [x] => 419
                            [y] => 304
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [x] => 479
                            [y] => 304
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [x] => 479
                            [y] => 397
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [x] => 419
                            [y] => 397
                        )

                )

        )

    [text] => a
)
```

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: No, unfortunately. Are you seeing it as well? (4 years later)

Comment: In one of our projects yes, it is not dependable when it comes to location of characters tbh, which is a shame, we will steer away for now until they fix this issue.